# apache2 not starting - even after reinstall - on Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: server, apache2, virtualhost

So I messed up my virtualhosts, and I did something that somehow broke my whole apache2 install. It wasn't starting, so I copied /var/www to ~/www and all of /etc/apache2/sites-available to ~/www too.
I haven't copied them back yet, but even after several purges, reinstalls, etc etc, it just doesn't work.

'apache2ctl configtest' is fine, no errors from there, and honestly, I'm really confused!

Any help would be much appreciated,
-Dan

Comment: What does 'I did something' mean?

Comment: I don't know - all I did change was the site's root in it's sites-available config file!

Comment: Please see `/var/log/` there should be a directory for apache logs there, please restart the server and post the last errors from the logs here by editing your question.